# CSV file to neighbor relation graph with 1's and 0's

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, graph, relation

There is a CSV file that contains states and their neighbors. In python, I want to create a graph with this file. How can I convert this data to a 2D List that can show connections with 1's and 0's.

**CSV**

| States | Neighbors |
| --- | --- |
| Florida | Alabama, Georgia |
| Alabama | Florida, Georgia, Tennessee, Mississippi |
| Tennessee | Alabama |
| Georgia | Alabama, Florida |
| Mississippi | Alabama |

**2D List** like this one but with only 1's and 0's

|  | Florida | Alabama | Tennessee | Georgia | Mississippi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Florida | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Alabama | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Tennessee | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Georgia | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Mississippi | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your sample data.

Comment: It seems OK in preview, but there is a problem in here.I couldn't fix that.

Comment: So what have you tried already? can you show your code?

Comment: You seem like you want a Pandas DataFrame as your output, not a 2-D list. If so, please edit your post to reflect this.

Comment: What you are calling "Cities" are actually "States".

Answer (score 1):

Try [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) + [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) + [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas-series-str-get-dummies) + [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas-dataframe-sum):

Then use [`fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html#numpy-fill-diagonal) to add the self relationships in:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cities': {0: 'Florida', 1: 'Alabama', 2: 'Tennessee', 3: 'Georgia',
               4: 'Mississippi'},
    'Neighbors': {0: 'Alabama, Georgia',
                  1: 'Florida, Georgia, Tennessee, Mississippi', 2: 'Alabama',
                  3: 'Alabama, Florida', 4: 'Alabama'}
})

# split and explode strings into rows convert to dummies then sum 
# to get totals per city
df = (
    df.set_index('Cities')['Neighbors'].str.split(', ')
        .explode()
        .str.get_dummies()
        .sum(level=0)
)

# Fill Diagonal to include self relationship as shown in output
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 1)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
             Alabama  Florida  Georgia  Mississippi  Tennessee
Alabama            1        1        1            1          1
Florida            1        1        1            0          0
Georgia            1        1        1            0          0
Mississippi        1        0        0            1          0
Tennessee          1        0        0            0          1
```

---

Or [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) + [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) + [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) + [`fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html#numpy-fill-diagonal):

```
# split and explode strings into rows
df = df.set_index('Cities')['Neighbors'].str.split(', ').explode()

# Cross tab to calculate relationship
df = pd.crosstab(df.index, df).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)

# Fill Diagonal to include self-relationship as shown in output
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 1)
```

`df`:

```
             Alabama  Florida  Georgia  Mississippi  Tennessee
Alabama            1        1        1            1          1
Florida            1        1        1            0          0
Georgia            1        1        1            0          0
Mississippi        1        0        0            1          0
Tennessee          1        0        0            0          1
```

---

To get a numpy array:

```
df.to_numpy()
```

```
[[1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1]]
```

or a list:

```
df.to_numpy().tolist()
```

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `.get_dummies` and `.sum(level=0)`:

```py
df["Neighbors"] = df["Neighbors"].str.split(", ")
df = pd.get_dummies(
    df.explode("Neighbors").set_index("Cities")["Neighbors"]
).sum(level=0)
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             Alabama  Florida  Georgia  Mississippi  Tennessee
Cities                                                        
Alabama            1        1        1            1          1
Florida            1        1        1            0          0
Georgia            1        1        1            0          0
Mississippi        1        0        0            1          0
Tennessee          1        0        0            0          1
```

Comment: `sum(level=0)` works too. instead of `groupby(level=0).sum()`

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks, TIL something new :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with graphs in Python, I strongly recommend the [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) package (docs [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/)).

It has many tools for manipulating graph representations as well as implementations of most common graph algorithms.

For example, suppose your graph is stored in CSV format where the first state on each line is followed by a list of its neighbors:

```sh
$ cat data.csv
Florida,Alabama,Georgia
Alabama,Florida,Georgia,Tennessee,Mississippi
Tennessee,Alabama
Georgia,Alabama,Florida
Mississippi,Alabama
```

Then you can read it in and view the adjacency matrix representation easily:

```py
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.read_adjlist("data.csv", delimiter=",")
>>> A = nx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix(G)
>>> A.todense()
matrix([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

An alternative to the adjacency matrix representation is to use a dict of dicts, which is sparse, indexed in the same fashion, and a bit easier to read:

```py
>>> nx.convert.to_dict_of_dicts(G, edge_data=1)
{'Florida': {'Alabama': 1, 'Georgia': 1}, 'Alabama': {'Florida': 1, 'Georgia': 1, 'Tennessee': 1, 'Mississippi': 1}, 'Georgia': {'Florida': 1, 'Alabama': 1}, 'Tennessee': {'Alabama': 1}, 'Mississippi': {'Alabama': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, import pandas and read data:

```
import pandas as pd

file = open('data.csv', 'r')
data = file.readlines()
```

'data' will look like this:

```
data

['Florida;Alabama,Georgia\n',
 'Alabama;Florida,Georgia,Tennessee,Mississippi\n',
 'Tennessee;Alabama\n',
 'Georgia;Alabama,Florida\n',
 'Mississippi;Alabama\n']
```

Fix your data to friendly format:

```
# creating a list of cities and its neighboors
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i].strip() # to remove '\n'
    data[i] = data[i].split(sep=';') # 'Florida;Alabama,Georgia' > ['Florida', 'Alabama,Georgia']
    data[i][1] = data[i][1].split(sep=',') # 'Alabama,Georgia' > ['Alabama', 'Georgia']
```

Your data will look like this (much better ):

```
data

 [['Florida', ['Alabama', 'Georgia']],
 ['Alabama', ['Florida', 'Georgia', 'Tennessee', 'Mississippi']],
 ['Tennessee', ['Alabama']],
 ['Georgia', ['Alabama', 'Florida']],
 ['Mississippi', ['Alabama']]]
```

Then, create a list of cities and neighboors. It will help you create DataFrame:

```
# creating a list of cities and neighboors
cities = []
neighboors = []
for d in data:
    cities.append(d[0])
    neighboors.extend(d[1])
neighboors = list(set(neighboors)) # to remove duplicates
```

Lists will look like this:

```
print('Cities List:', cities,'\nNeighboors List:', neighboors)

Cities List: ['Florida', 'Alabama', 'Tennessee', 'Georgia', 'Mississippi'] 
Neighboors List: ['Mississippi', 'Alabama', 'Georgia', 'Florida', 'Tennessee']
```

Then, create a dataframe and replace nan to 0 or 1, according to 'data':

```
# creating a dataframe with columns and index
df = pd.DataFrame(index=cities, columns=neighboors)

# replace nan to 1 or 0
for d in data:
    for n in d[1]:
        df.loc[d[0], n] = 1
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

'df' will look like this:

[result df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q85fQ.png)

I hope it helped you